# Dos executable lookup except PATH

Tags: windows, command-line, lookup

I have a cmd open (Windows 7), and I type "java.exe", and the system finds the executable at c:\program files\java\jre6\bin.

However, this folder is not in the path. What other mechanism affect the exe lookup?

Comment: Is there any variable like JRE_HOME , JAVA__HOME in your path,It can also execute

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting with Vista and above, Windows now includes a utility called `where`. This program functions just like you'd expect the unix counterpart to (I'm glad they added it!)

Usage:

```
C:\>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
```

What's even nicer about `where` is that it'll show you all executables it finds within your path, so if you also had java.exe in C:\Windows it would show up *under* the \System32\ one.

**EDIT**

I figured I'd also include an option for XP users that would like the functionality without third party tools. Raymond Chen wrote a command script in [A 90-byte "whereis" program](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/20/357225.aspx). It's a nice one liner that accomplishes the same task!

```
@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in (%1%%e) do @if NOT "%%~$PATH:i"=="" echo %%~$PATH:i
```

Save the above script in a .bat or .cmd file and you can launch it from the command line with the filename as the argument. It'll work just like you expect! (note, if using the script version, leave off the extension, it'll search all executable extensions for you)

Comment: +1 Always prefer a native solution 'where' possible :)

Comment: +1; never knew about this command before! (And I used to think I was pretty handy with the command line!)

Comment: +1 for new-to-me. It works similarly to the `find` command in Unix (unlike the `find` command in DOS or Windows). You can do `where -r \users\username\documents *.xl*` for example.

Comment: +1 thanks for the XP script - I saved it as `where.bat` and it works just like vista would! :)

Comment: The *nix equivalent is "which".  The "where" one is a script on redhat perhaps for people that forget that it is 'which' on *nix

Answer (score 2):

there's a copy of java.exe in c:\windows\system32 (which is a path defined in the environment variables). that's the one that comes up when you type java.exe at the command prompt, not the one in c:\program files\java\jre6\bin.

Comment: You don't say. I tried using 'which.exe' to find it, but it didn't.

Comment: works for me.  which which are you using?

Comment: My which is cygwin's which and which java whiched the java.exe in /system32, so whichever which you're using might be bewitched.

Comment: gnuwin32's which.

Comment: cygwin which here too.  (witch hair 2?)

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way to look up files location in path using powershell:

```
(Get-Command java).Source
```